# Tailwind CSS: How do I make an element sticky and full height?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How can I achieve it in this particular case? I need the "sidebar two" element to always stick and not scroll with the page (like sidebar and header)

I also can't rigidly add a value e.g. `calc (100% - 40px)`, because there may also be an optional top header As in the example

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="sticky left-0 top-0 w-24 h-screen bg-gray-800">sidebar</div>

  <div class="flex-1">
    <div class="h-6 bg-gray-500">optional top header</div>

    <header class="sticky left-0 top-0 h-10 bg-gray-600">header</header>

    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-none w-44 bg-gray-700">sidebar two</div>

      <div class="flex-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae
        ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at exercitationem
        adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora, sit exercitationem
        consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo quae perspiciatis
        eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta, minima optio cum
        voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita cumque in numquam,
        quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error dolorum, alias voluptates,
        eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis facere placeat aspernatur sequi,
        quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae ducimus libero dolore, veritatis
        necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at exercitationem adipisci quasi autem,
        illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora, sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis
        modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus
        illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta, minima optio cum voluptates recusandae,
        nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum
        nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate,
        libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed.
        Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus
        hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae
        accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora, sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam
        inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate
        molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta, minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe
        qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis?
        Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero
        expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem,
        magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique
        repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem
        eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam
        quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora, sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis
        fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium
        animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta, minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi
        eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis
        a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque?
        Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora
        quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis quibusdam molestias dignissimos aut fugit rerum quam facere corrupti minus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/YO4rrf6PA1

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve exactly? Do you want the text to stay as it is when the user scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem by making the `sidebar two` fixed. You can check at https://play.tailwindcss.com/2IZ5vCYpOO

Comment: This covers some of the right hand column text.

Comment: Yes, and you can decrease the width of the sidebar and change the right-hand column accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I can think of so far is to add a dummy div into the flex to make sure the text moves to the second column the right amount and to take the actual sidebar out of that flex and fix it.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style id="_style">
    /*! tailwindcss v2.2.7 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */
    /*! modern-normalize v1.1.0 | MIT License | https://github.com/sindresorhus/modern-normalize */
    /*
Document
========
*/
    /**
Use a better box model (opinionated).
*/
    
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /**
Use a more readable tab size (opinionated).
*/
    
    html {
      -moz-tab-size: 4;
      -o-tab-size: 4;
      tab-size: 4;
    }
    /**
1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
*/
    
    html {
      line-height: 1.15;
      /* 1 */
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /*
Sections
========
*/
    /**
Remove the margin in all browsers.
*/
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    /**
Improve consistency of default fonts in all browsers. (https://github.com/sindresorhus/modern-normalize/issues/3)
*/
    
    body {
      font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, /* Firefox supports this but not yet `system-ui` */
      'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji';
    }
    /*
Grouping content
================
*/
    /**
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
*/
    
    hr {
      height: 0;
      /* 1 */
      color: inherit;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /*
Text-level semantics
====================
*/
    /**
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/
    
    abbr[title] {
      -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
      text-decoration: underline dotted;
    }
    /**
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/
    
    b,
    strong {
      font-weight: bolder;
    }
    /**
1. Improve consistency of default fonts in all browsers. (https://github.com/sindresorhus/modern-normalize/issues/3)
2. Correct the odd 'em' font sizing in all browsers.
*/
    
    code,
    kbd,
    samp,
    pre {
      font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Menlo, monospace;
      /* 1 */
      font-size: 1em;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /**
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/
    
    small {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
    /**
Prevent 'sub' and 'sup' elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/
    
    sub,
    sup {
      font-size: 75%;
      line-height: 0;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    
    sub {
      bottom: -0.25em;
    }
    
    sup {
      top: -0.5em;
    }
    /*
Tabular data
============
*/
    /**
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
*/
    
    table {
      text-indent: 0;
      /* 1 */
      border-color: inherit;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /*
Forms
=====
*/
    /**
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
*/
    
    button,
    input,
    optgroup,
    select,
    textarea {
      font-family: inherit;
      /* 1 */
      font-size: 100%;
      /* 1 */
      line-height: 1.15;
      /* 1 */
      margin: 0;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /**
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
*/
    
    button,
    select {
      /* 1 */
      text-transform: none;
    }
    /**
Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
*/
    
    button,
    [type='button'],
    [type='reset'],
    [type='submit'] {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
    }
    /**
Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
*/
    
    ::-moz-focus-inner {
      border-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /**
Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
*/
    
    :-moz-focusring {
      outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
    }
    /**
Remove the additional ':invalid' styles in Firefox.
See: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737
*/
    
    :-moz-ui-invalid {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    /**
Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out 'fieldset' elements in all browsers.
*/
    
    legend {
      padding: 0;
    }
    /**
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/
    
    progress {
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /**
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/
    
    ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
      height: auto;
    }
    /**
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/
    
    [type='search'] {
      -webkit-appearance: textfield;
      /* 1 */
      outline-offset: -2px;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /**
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/
    
    ::-webkit-search-decoration {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    /**
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to 'inherit' in Safari.
*/
    
    ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      /* 1 */
      font: inherit;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /*
Interactive
===========
*/
    /*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/
    
    summary {
      display: list-item;
    }
    /**
 * Manually forked from SUIT CSS Base: https://github.com/suitcss/base
 * A thin layer on top of normalize.css that provides a starting point more
 * suitable for web applications.
 */
    /**
 * Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
 */
    
    blockquote,
    dl,
    dd,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    hr,
    figure,
    p,
    pre {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    button {
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
    }
    
    fieldset {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ol,
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /**
 * Tailwind custom reset styles
 */
    /**
 * 1. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family (with Tailwind's default
 *    sans-serif font stack as a fallback) as a sane default.
 * 2. Use Tailwind's default "normal" line-height so the user isn't forced
 *    to override it to ensure consistency even when using the default theme.
 */
    
    html {
      font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
      /* 1 */
      line-height: 1.5;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /**
 * Inherit font-family and line-height from `html` so users can set them as
 * a class directly on the `html` element.
 */
    
    body {
      font-family: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
    /**
 * 1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width.
 *
 *    We used to set this in the html element and inherit from
 *    the parent element for everything else. This caused issues
 *    in shadow-dom-enhanced elements like <details> where the content
 *    is wrapped by a div with box-sizing set to `content-box`.
 *
 *    https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4
 *
 *
 * 2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width.
 *
 *    By default, the way the browser specifies that an element should have no
 *    border is by setting it's border-style to `none` in the user-agent
 *    stylesheet.
 *
 *    In order to easily add borders to elements by just setting the `border-width`
 *    property, we change the default border-style for all elements to `solid`, and
 *    use border-width to hide them instead. This way our `border` utilities only
 *    need to set the `border-width` property instead of the entire `border`
 *    shorthand, making our border utilities much more straightforward to compose.
 *
 *    https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116
 */
    
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* 1 */
      border-width: 0;
      /* 2 */
      border-style: solid;
      /* 2 */
      border-color: currentColor;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /*
 * Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default
 */
    
    hr {
      border-top-width: 1px;
    }
    /**
 * Undo the `border-style: none` reset that Normalize applies to images so that
 * our `border-{width}` utilities have the expected effect.
 *
 * The Normalize reset is unnecessary for us since we default the border-width
 * to 0 on all elements.
 *
 * https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/362
 */
    
    img {
      border-style: solid;
    }
    
    textarea {
      resize: vertical;
    }
    
    input::-moz-placeholder,
    textarea::-moz-placeholder {
      opacity: 1;
      color: #9ca3af;
    }
    
    input:-ms-input-placeholder,
    textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
      opacity: 1;
      color: #9ca3af;
    }
    
    input::placeholder,
    textarea::placeholder {
      opacity: 1;
      color: #9ca3af;
    }
    
    button,
    [role="button"] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-size: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
    }
    /**
 * Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of
 * opt-out.
 */
    
    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: inherit;
    }
    /**
 * Reset form element properties that are easy to forget to
 * style explicitly so you don't inadvertently introduce
 * styles that deviate from your design system. These styles
 * supplement a partial reset that is already applied by
 * normalize.css.
 */
    
    button,
    input,
    optgroup,
    select,
    textarea {
      padding: 0;
      line-height: inherit;
      color: inherit;
    }
    /**
 * Use the configured 'mono' font family for elements that
 * are expected to be rendered with a monospace font, falling
 * back to the system monospace stack if there is no configured
 * 'mono' font family.
 */
    
    pre,
    code,
    kbd,
    samp {
      font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
    }
    /**
 * 1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default as that's
 *    the behavior you want almost all of the time. Inspired by
 *    CSS Remedy, with `svg` added as well.
 *
 *    https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14
 * 
 * 2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more
 *    sensibly by default when overriding `display` by adding a
 *    utility like `inline`.
 *
 *    This can trigger a poorly considered linting error in some
 *    tools but is included by design.
 * 
 *    https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210
 */
    
    img,
    svg,
    video,
    canvas,
    audio,
    iframe,
    embed,
    object {
      display: block;
      /* 1 */
      vertical-align: middle;
      /* 2 */
    }
    /**
 * Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve
 * their intrinsic aspect ratio.
 *
 * https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14
 */
    
    img,
    video {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    /**
 * Ensure the default browser behavior of the `hidden` attribute.
 */
    
    [hidden] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: sticky;
    }
    
    .left-0 {
      left: 0px;
    }
    
    .top-0 {
      top: 0px;
    }
    
    .flex {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .h-screen {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .h-6 {
      height: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .h-10 {
      height: 2.5rem;
    }
    
    .w-24 {
      width: 6rem;
    }
    
    .w-44 {
      width: 11rem;
    }
    
    .flex-1 {
      flex: 1 1 0%;
    }
    
    .flex-none {
      flex: none;
    }
    
    .bg-gray-200 {
      --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(229, 231, 235, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }
    
    .bg-gray-800 {
      --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(31, 41, 55, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }
    
    .bg-gray-500 {
      --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(107, 114, 128, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }
    
    .bg-gray-600 {
      --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(75, 85, 99, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }
    
    .bg-gray-700 {
      --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(55, 65, 81, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var hasHtml = false
    var hasCss = false
    var visible = false
    window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      if (typeof e.data.clear !== 'undefined') {
        setHtml()
        setCss()
        checkVisibility()
        return
      }
      if (typeof e.data.css !== 'undefined') {
        setCss(e.data.css)
      }
      if (typeof e.data.html !== 'undefined') {
        setHtml(e.data.html)
      }
      checkVisibility()
    })

    function checkVisibility() {
      if (!visible && hasHtml && hasCss) {
        visible = true
        document.body.style.display = ''
      } else if (visible && (!hasHtml || !hasCss)) {
        visible = false
        document.body.style.display = 'none'
      }
    }

    function setHtml(html) {
      if (typeof html === 'undefined') {
        document.body.innerHTML = ''
        hasHtml = false
      } else {
        document.body.innerHTML = html
        hasHtml = true
      }
    }

    function setCss(css) {
      const style = document.getElementById('_style')
      const newStyle = document.createElement('style')
      newStyle.id = '_style'
      newStyle.innerHTML = typeof css === 'undefined' ? '' : css
      style.parentNode.replaceChild(newStyle, style)
      hasCss = typeof css === 'undefined' ? false : true
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body style="">
  <div class="flex bg-gray-200">
    <div class="sticky left-0 top-0 w-24 h-screen bg-gray-800">sidebar</div>

    <div class="flex-1">
      <div class="h-6 bg-gray-500">optional top header</div>

      <header class="sticky left-0 top-0 h-10 bg-gray-600">header</header>


      <div class="flex-none w-44 bg-gray-700" style="background-color: pink; position: fixed;">sidebar two</div>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex-none w-44 bg-gray-700"></div>

        <div class="flex-1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae
          ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at
          exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora,
          sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo
          quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta,
          minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita
          cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error
          dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis
          facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae
          ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at
          exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora,
          sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo
          quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta,
          minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita
          cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error
          dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis
          facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae
          ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at
          exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora,
          sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo
          quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta,
          minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita
          cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error
          dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis
          facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem similique repudiandae voluptate ad, ullam necessitatibus deleniti ab cumque, error neque culpa, minus fuga unde alias ipsum! Aspernatur vel odit architecto? Blanditiis quidem numquam, vitae
          ducimus libero dolore, veritatis necessitatibus hic explicabo dolorem eius odit possimus, rem architecto commodi nesciunt officiis? Error id repudiandae magnam modi facere doloribus reiciendis quasi est! Cum nemo repudiandae quos possimus at
          exercitationem adipisci quasi autem, illo eaque quae accusantium non quibusdam quod dolorum, veniam optio, eligendi nisi ipsam accusamus quaerat assumenda vitae. Esse, consectetur corporis! Placeat nam temporibus sunt quas et nihil tempora,
          sit exercitationem consectetur veritatis modi quibusdam inventore ducimus blanditiis fugiat vero odio expedita voluptates laudantium ratione sequi. Dolores deserunt suscipit delectus nostrum. Placeat dolorem rem ipsa soluta, assumenda odit explicabo
          quae perspiciatis eum. Sed accusamus illum cupiditate molestiae quia accusantium animi. Velit, et. Ullam veritatis aut sapiente vitae harum architecto sed fuga. Ducimus pariatur reiciendis culpa tempore mollitia corporis aspernatur, odio dicta,
          minima optio cum voluptates recusandae, nihil saepe qui quasi consectetur ex commodi eaque officia dolore illum? Fugit et beatae adipisci! Obcaecati esse incidunt eaque iure ex porro, pariatur unde, quia impedit nam a temporibus doloremque expedita
          cumque in numquam, quasi ut quod ipsum nobis? Labore soluta voluptatem perferendis a est. Soluta labore voluptatem veritatis alias vitae maiores minima dicta, repellat quidem repellendus obcaecati. Neque sit cupiditate atque consequuntur error
          dolorum, alias voluptates, eius voluptate, libero expedita quasi officiis fuga doloremque? Rerum nihil quidem officiis obcaecati fugit quia maxime nisi doloremque, reprehenderit eveniet enim debitis iusto in earum nesciunt nobis, perferendis
          facere placeat aspernatur sequi, quos vel sed. Voluptatem, magnam officiis. Delectus tempora quod quasi reiciendis sapiente libero accusamus sit exercitationem enim, totam maxime molestiae fugit dolorum placeat praesentium quae? Veritatis quibusdam
          molestias dignissimos aut fugit rerum quam facere corrupti minus.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```